# gVim 7.3 in fullscreen mode

Tags: fullscreen, vim

I'm using the script to open gVim in fullscreen downloaded from here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2596.

I've also added this line to the startup settings:

```
:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
```

When running gVim with this setting, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing _virmc:
E364: Library call failed for "ToggleFullScreen()"
```

Is there anything else I need to do with the files from that script? If I need to compile it somehow, would like someone to guide me through that process as I'm fairly new to Vim. Thanks!

Edit: I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean `~/.vimrc` or `~/.gvimrc` by "startup settings". When that is executed, the GUI isn't initialized yet. Try delaying the execution with an autocmd:

```
:autocmd GUIEnter * call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be working if you place that `call` line in your `vimrc`. It should be called after Vim has finished loading. I suggest using that mapping from the readme:

```
map <F11> <Esc>:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)<CR>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was install this script through [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).
It's solved the problem:

> Copy the DLL to the folder where GVIM.EXE is located.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to copying the `gvimfullscreen.dll` to the executable directory is to specify the file path, like this:

```
call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/bundle/gvimfullscreen_win32/gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
```

In this example, I'm using `$VIM` and the `bundle` directory, but you can change this to a full path, or use another variable/path that works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but after searching for a solution for quite a while, I've decided that the prettiest way to run Vim on Windows is via Cygwin, via the (bundled) mintty terminal. It has a genuine full screen and even transparencies!

Comment: One of the problems of using vim in Cygwin is that it becomes excruciatingly slow once you install big plugins, such as YouCompleteMe, due to the fork+exec performance of cygwin.  There is still much to gain from using gVim natively.